# Language Support In A PHP App With MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to provide language support in several different languages in a php web application. There are obviously several different ways to do this. In the past I used to store a variable in a php file for every language such as `en.php` for english support and `fr.php` for french support. For example, for the words `Good Morning` I would store it in a key `$goodmorning` then define it in both files and point to one or the other file with an if statement depending on user input.

It worked great but it was a lot of work. Is there a more efficient way to do this? I thought about storing the words in a database table called 
language_support. The table would look as follow

```
id | en    | fr   | es   |last_update
1  | hello | allo | hola | 04/12/2018
```

But my question is, how would I teach my program to recognize the words?

Comment: You know this is way too broad right?  Especially since you haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: That's not how languages work. For example, "point" in English can mean a bunch of different things, and each of those meanings may have different translations.

Comment: @tadman: You are correct and I agree. But I would store entire expressions.

Comment: That's still not enough. You'll need, at the absolute least, a phrase and a free-form "context" field. "Home" in the context of a menu, for example, often translates in surprisingly different ways than "Home" in other contexts.

Comment: That's a really bad design for storing different translations. A better one would be `create table translation( base_lang_string varchar (200), translate_to_lang varchar(5), translated varchar(200) primary key (base_lang_strinf, translate_to_lang));`

Answer (score 1):

Look into PHP's _() and __() functions. This is for multi-language support of internal strings, not content. In other words, it's for the "Press any key to continue" or "Enter customer name" prompts, not for the blog articles. The general way it works is that you have a text file for each language, each text file with all the internal strings in the source and target languages.

You would use, for example, `_("Good Morning!")`, and assuming you had set the language to German, the output would be "Guten Tag!"

I'm at work, so I can't show you any PHP code right now, but that should be enough to Google. :)